# Do the stormtroopers wear their stormtrooper armor when they mop the floors?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi, stormtroopers, first-order

Finn mentions that he was in sanitation, and his knowledge of First Order bases and ships seems predicated on the fact that he cleans up around those bases/ships (which seems like it should be beneath a stormtrooper, but, that's not the point of this question). Does he wear his stormtrooper armor while working sanitation? If not, what does a stormtrooper wear while performing sanitation duties?

Comment: A storm trooper is required to wear their uniform during their entire shift. This is why Phasma made a point of asking why Finn had taken off his helmet during TFA. The armor is part of the storm trooper uniform and military forces wear their uniform whenever they are "on duty." I'm not saying whether storm troopers mop or not, but if one was, he would wear his uniform while he did it.

Comment: Also, in the military there are no housekeepers.  Everyone is sanitation at some point.  At some point in your career you will operate a mop and clean a toilet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I pointed out [in another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/177567/20774), stormtroopers don't pull sanitation duty, that's something that falls to stormtrooper ***cadets***.

Assuming the training regime is similar to that of the former Empire, a cadet would wear a soft jacket and trousers.

[image]