# Why not use Droids for sanitation duty?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers, first-order

Why did the elite Stormtroopers have sanitation duties when they had millions of slave workers with no personhood-rights whatsoever?

Comment: children need chores

Comment: You don't give slave workers tasks that make it easy for them to escape.

Comment: Except that droids don't seem to have any desire to run away (Artoo notwithstanding)

Comment: Its name is R2-D2, not "artoo".

Comment: @Typhon - https://puu.sh/yQafq/23e5a2a5ca.png - Straight from the Wikia

Comment: @Typhon - it's a common phoentical spelling - used in nearly all the canon materials, including the scripts. Artoo and Bee-Bee-Ate

Comment: Wow, and here I thought only the fans were butchering the name.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sanitation is a low-level duty. Basically you do it while you're a cadet, long before you get to go out and shoot people.

> After years of training, FN-2187 had itched for some real action. **Like
> other stormtrooper cadets, he’d rotated through several lower-level
> duties, including a janitorial assignment,** but he hadn’t seen any real
> live-fire action yet.
>
> <sub><sup>Star Wars: Finn's Story</sup></sub>

and

> They were stormtroopers, but they weren’t quite, not yet. They were cadets, and **as cadets they had additional duties aside from their training.** Those duties covered everything from maintaining the armory to performing minor repairs on equipment to quite literally moving equipment from one location to another, often by hand but frequently with the assistance of the heavy-lifter droids, when whatever was to be moved was too big to be moved manually. **They mopped the floors. They emptied the trash.** They worked in the galley preparing meals.
>
> <sub><sup>Star Wars: Before the Awakening.</sup></sub>

The goal seems to be that since you have a large force of cadet troops, you might as well get them to do something useful with their off-time. It teaches them about the base, about military discipline and procedures and about the importance of keeping their shit wired tight.

Comment: so it's more about the idle hands of the troops than about needing someone to get these things done?

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach - You might as well ask why they have squaddies clean toilet stalls with toothbrushes when you could achieve the same in seconds with a mop. Sometimes it's not about efficiency.

Comment: Why *do* they have squaddies clean toilet stalls with toothbrushes?  I always thought that was more a silly TV and movie thing that something that actually happens...

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach - It's was moderately uncommon before the 1980s and now vanishingly uncommon since the advent of human rights legislation. That being said, it's not unheard-of; https://www.quora.com/In-the-military-do-they-actually-make-you-scrub-the-floors-with-a-toothbrush

Comment: This will no doubt come as a surprise to the people assigned extra duty as a form of punishment for minor offenses, which still happens.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach its a tedious, disgusting punishment - same thing as cutting a lawn with nail scissors or painting a wall with cotton ear buds. It's just a punishment which is bad enough that you want to avoid it at all cost - people can weather being shouted at or put in a cell for a night, but give them several hours of tedium beyond tedium and they *will* think twice.  It's the same as writing lines.

Comment: My grandfather severed in the NSA back in 1953 and after he died we got his service records. There's a report in there from when he was tasked with observing and report on the conditions of the mess hall cafeteria. Literal busy work. It was done just too insure every man had something to do while they were on duty. It would not surprise me that stormtroopers would have similar duties.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach : that's still nothing, compared to what they do to recruits in the French Foreign Legion.

Answer (score 9):

Fatigue duty is a long established military tradition. In the British military one form of punishment is "Restrictions of Privileges" and would usually involve repeated inspections of uniform and kit mixed with assorted menial tasks that could include, yes, sanitation duty. The American UCMJ allows the assignment of fatigue duty (over and above regular duties) as a form of non-judicial punishment, and the Canadian Forces allows the assignment of extra work in similar circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

There is no other viable reason, except to portray Finn as someone who didn't bloody his hands (literally and figuratively :) ) until events of Episode VII . Note that many (all) armies in real world use soldiers for sanitation duties, partially to keep them busy and partially to reduce costs. But in SW universe there is no real reason for that, droids would be more effective and stormtroopers could spend more time preparing for combat.

Answer (score 1):

At least some special forces maintain their own barracks which is probably partly out of convince but I have heard that it is to teach humility.

Alternatively to make the force self reliant, so that when stationed on a ship if the plumbers are killed/destroyed the combat troops can take over. A marine stationed on a ship doesn't just wait until they are near the shore before doing anything.

Least plausible for in the film but possible is the First Order wants every soldier to learn a civilian trade before they are retired. The forces care about the well being of their members as much as the country cares about not having a former army with mental disorders and no job prospects.

Comment: Yeah, the First Order totally cares about its stormtroopers ; being abducted at childhood and forced to integrate is a good display of attention.

Comment: @Kamalen for arguments sake it could be that the decision to abduct stormtroopers was made by a different group to those that oversee training, organisations are never single entities. The only known abduction of a stormtrooper happened twenty something years ago in a volatile period in the galaxy, things may have changed, or the First Order feel guilt over their need to pressgang soldiers and are trying to make amends. In any case I am sure the First Order would see the 'abduction' as legally conscripting the Empires citizens and giving them the most time possible to train and ensure survival